# Software availability

Tags: 13.04, windows, wine, virtualbox, photoshop

I've been using Ubuntu for the past year or so, and I swear, I have turned into the biggest Ubuntu Fanboy in the world, I absolutely love everything about Ubuntu except for this one little thing. Software availability T.T.

I need certain softwares to do the things I need, I'm a web designer/graphic designer and I'll be honest, I miss Photoshop. GIMP is great and all, but its considerably less in comparison to Photoshop.
Another software I need badly is Manga Studio 4.0 I've run it through WINE but it doesn't pick up the sensitivity on my tablet, and its very unresponsive, which is bad because its supposed to be a precise software that I use to save some money on Ink and for adding screentones to my drawings.
These are the only 2 softwares I really need and its the only reason I'm planning on going back to Windows when I get my new computer.

My question is, are there anyways I can use these softwares without having to go back to Windows, I was planning on getting a VirtualBox software but my current CPU can't handle the strain. 
I'm getting a new CPU sometime this month with these specs

Processor: Intel 7 Dual-Core 3.0ghz

RAM: 8gb

HDD: 1TB

G-Card: nVidia Geforce GT 645 M

Are these Specs good enough to run a Virtual Box as smoothly as possible?

This WILL be a custom PC so specs are upgradeable before I order it, so I could get the best PC possible, please help out. I really want to stay with Ubuntu no matter what, and I really don't want to have to Dual-Boot everytime I want to use a certain software T.T.

Comment: Then, it's not a problem of software availability, it's a problem of a user that expects an OS to run programs that were not designed for that OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need more ram if you are thinking to work with Photoshop.

I was working on a menu for a restaurant and when i was almost done with the project was pretty hard to work on it because photoshop was really slow. Photoshop was using  4.6-5.0 GB Ram and i wasn't using virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think Photoshop operates according to the principle "The more resources the better".

However, I think that your machine has enough power so that the visualization overhead will be acceptable.